# rails / ruby date calculation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

In my application, users can either (a) select from a drop-down with dates or (b) use a datepicker to create a personal date range.

This code works for selected drop-down dates:

```
  date_from  = Date.parse('2012-10-01')
  date_to    = Date.parse('2013-09-30')
  @year_one  = date_from..date_to
```

Year one is defined as `2012-10-01..2013-09-30`

The user can also create an arbitrary range: `@user.cpa_cycle_start` to `@user.cpa_cycle_end`.  Only the `@user.cpa_cycle_end` is used in this calculation and it doesn't work:

```
  a = @user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s
  b = @user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s
  date_from  = (Date.parse(a) - 3.years)
  date_to    = (Date.parse(b) - 2.years)
  @year_one  = date_from..date_to
```

The error message is `Invalid date`  Before trying this iteration, I tried placing `@user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s` in the ():

```
  date_from  = (Date.parse(@user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s) - 3.years)
  date_to    = (Date.parse(@user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s) - 2.years)
  @year_one  = date_from..date_to
```

I thought passing the date as a variable might work; however, neither approach works.  (Coincidentally, using `24.months` and `36.months` rather than years doesn't make a difference either.)

How can I get the range: `@year_one  = date_from..date_to`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Seems like the string you are getting from the datepicker isn't parseable.  Have you tried looking at it with the debugger, or printing it before you parse it?

Comment: We need to know what kind of object is returned by `@user.cpa_cycle_end` (class, value, etc), and what's returned by `to_s`.

Comment: Both `@user.cpa_cycle_end` and `@user.cpa_cycle_end.to_s` return a date, e.g., 2016-01-29, without quotes.  So, I tried this: `a = @user.cpa_cycle_end`, `date_from = (a - 3.years)` and `date_to = (a - 2.years)` .  Then, I raised `@year_one` and got the error: undefined method `-' for "2016-01-29":String`  Also, while I didn't initially note it, I `require date` in the model / this file.